# To find wednesday between to dates given by the user

Tags: java

I need to find wednesday for the two dates given by the user.
example:
Inputs are:
from date:07-Feb-2013
To date:13-feb-2013
The gap between the from date and To date is 7 days always.
Expected Output:12-feb-2013

```
public String getAutoDayExpiryDateAndToDate(String instrmentId,String deliveryAutoFromDate)
    throws SystemException, FunctionalException,ParseException
    {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date(deliveryAutoFromDate));
        Date fromDate=calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formatedDate = sf1.format(fromDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,-1);
        Date time = calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String formatedDate1 = sf.format(time);
    }
```

after these i need to find Wednesday which is present between formatedDate  and formatedDate1 .how can i do it??

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class. Set it to the first date, and then check if the current day of the week is Wednesday by calling `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`. Perform this check in a loop, adding a day to the current date during each iteration. This will never take more than seven steps, so you don't need to do anything fancier than that.

Comment: @user2000842 I believe this answer provides enough information for you to complete the code by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

this should find the first Wednesday after (or equal) the given date

```
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 1, 7);
    if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) <= Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.WEDNESDAY - c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    } else {
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 11 - c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));          
    }
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

prints

```
Wed Feb 13 00:00:00 EET 2013
```

you can test it to see if it gives you what you want